# Problem: "name '_eval_expr' is not defined" even though it should be

Tags: python, python-3.x

so im having some trouble with my code and i have asked some programmer friends what could be wrong because i couldnt figure it out before coming here, but they didnt know either.

in theory it shouldve worked and i actually copy pasted half of it from a different project i have and it works fine there, but not in this code for some reason. working with the github api to get code and then run that code, but i get can error

```
# code

async def parse_str_code(files):
    for f in get_files(files):
        if isinstance(f.encoding, str):
            code = format_content(f.content)
            fn_name = "_eval_expr"
            code = code.strip("` ")
            code = "\n".join(f"    {i}" for i in code.splitlines())
            body = f"async def {fn_name}():\n{code}"
            print(body)
            parsed = ast.parse(body)
            body = parsed.body[0].body
            insert_returns(body)
            env = {}
            exec(compile(parsed, filename="filename", mode="exec"), env)
            await eval(f"{fn_name}()", d)


asyncio.run(parse_str_code(files))

# error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/namepy/python/project_running_code_with_github/main.py", line 73, in <module>
    asyncio.run(parse_str_code(files))
  File "D:\name\python\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "D:\name\python\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 608, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "D:/name/python/project_running_code_with_github/main.py", line 68, in parse_str_code
    await eval(f"{fn_name}()", d)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_eval_expr' is not defined
```

Comment: What is `d`? Should that be `env`?

Comment: Seems dangerous to just blindly evaluate code

Comment: @Barmar oh i didnt realize that, that turns out to be it lmao. thank you

Comment: @OneCricketeer i control where the code comes from, shouldve mention that sorry lol